# regexp_extract in hive giving error

Tags: regex, hive

I have some data in table e.g.:

```
id,params  
123,utm_content=doit|utm_source=direct|   
234,utm_content=polo|utm_source=AndroidNew|
```

desired data using regexp_extract:

```
id,channel,content
123,direct,doit
234,AndroidNew,polo
```

Query used:

```
Select id, REGEXP_extract(lower(params),'(.*utm_source=)([^\|]*)(\|*)',2) as channel, REGEXP_extract(lower(params),'(.*utm_content=)([^\|]*)(\|*)',2)  as content from table;
```

It is showing error '* dangling meta character' and returning error code 2

Can someone help here please??

Comment: What is your regex supposed to match? Note that in hive, you need to double the backslashes, and your regex should look like `(.*utm_content=)([^|]*)(\\|*)`. I believe you are looking for `([0-9]*),utm_content=([^|]*)\\|utm_source=([^|]*)`

Comment: \\ worked. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: I posted since that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in **`hive`,** you need to double the backslashes.

Your regex should look like

```
(.*utm_content=)([^|]*)(\\|*)
```